# What is the correct site to ask about new stop-start feature in automobiles?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently I read about a stop-start feature in automobiles.  It is designed to reduce pollution by stopping the engine when the car is stopped, and starting the engine automatically when the gas pedal is pressed.

A friend and I were discussing.  Our gut reaction is to doubt this saves much energy.  Where is the correct site to ask about this?  Specifically, we are interested in the energy saved (running the engine vs. restart).  I know this area could be quite broad, so I want to narrow my question a bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)?

From their [help center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for **researching the evidence behind claims you encounter**. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

And guess what! You aren't the first to ask this. See this well-received question on that site: [Does a start-stop system for a combustion engine pay off?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19317).